# Why date format is different in different devices?

Tags: java, android

I am using android.text.format.Dateformat package. For same locale, I am getting two different date formats. For example, US - 7/21/2017 and in another device as 7/21/17. First device is with API 18 and second one is API 24.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are using `DateFormat` that is giving you these results.

Answer (score 0):

Different JRE implementations can have variations in how classes are implemented, even across versions. Your two devices likely have small variations in the default US date format, as in 2 vs 4 digits years.

You need to provide some code and JRE details if you want further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

`android.text.format.Dateformat` will print strings that take into account the preferences set in the user's settings app. Almost every phone will allow you to choose between 12-hour and 24-hour time (e.g. 3:00 PM vs 15:00), but some phones also allow you to choose the format you'd like to see dates in.

I suspect your first phone's setting is `M/d/yyyy` and your second phone's is `M/d/yy`.